# Biomedical Image Segmentation

Tags: image-segmentation, training-data

In brain tumor segmentation,can I consider Images and Labels as color images?
Or images can have 3 channels but Ground Truth/ Mask/ Label must be in 1 channel. Or both must be of 1 channel?? As I have used both (images & GT) of 3 channels for UNET architecture, and giving me output as blank colored image. Why output is so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no necessary to use colored images to perform biomedical image segmentation. The value of CT/MR image has a specific meaning, which denotes different lesions such as bones or vessels.
If you use 3 channels, I don't know whether the value still has the same meaning or not. Also, I do not recommend you take the GT as 3 channels image, because the voxel value denotes different classes. In your case, maybe 1-n for different kinds of tumors, 0 for background.
Thus, 3 channels representation will lose some semantic information, make the problem more complex.